# Should I convert categorical variables to continuos variables for SEM(Structural Equation Model)?

Tags: variables, input, categorical-data, structural-equation-model

Now, I trying to use SEM for checking HBN(Hierarchical Bayesian Network) structure.
I have ordered categorical independent variables and binary categorical dependent variable.
So, Should I convert that variables to continuos variables or dummy coding??
Can I just put the variables value like 'low', 'mid', 'high'...?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Possibly you will find richer discussions at [Cross Validated][https://stats.stackexchange.com/] if the intent is to get a more methodological discussion. Here, the discussion is focused on coding... and a mention of a package (programming language or tool - are you using R? Python?) and a minimal code with a reproducible example is required to have better chances of getting useful answers...

Answer (score 0):

You do have not a minimal code with a reproducible example, so, I am not able to enter specificities... But generally speaking, depends on the package (and programming language) you use, but:

- binary data should be kept as binary (TRUE/FALSE, 1/0 usually accepted and identified as binary),
- and ordinal ones kept as ordinal. It means, that recording the ordinal as numeric (or factor) 1, 2, and 3 usually makes sense, to keep it ordinal. Converting it into string/character would be treating it as nominal (like in blue/yellow/black, no order). If the function accepts both (factor, character), possibly you need to specify explicitly their how to treat it/variable type).